# What do you call the range of possible subjects a word can be predicated of

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-subject

What do you call the range of possible subjects a word can be predicated of?

i.e., brown can be predicated of furniture but not numbers; running can be predicated of people but not rocks; fruitless can be predicated of actions but not objects; etc etc.

So is there a definition that generalizes on this and describes all possible subjects of a predicate?

Comment: Numbers can be brown if you're synaesthetic. Rocks can run a race down hill. People, companies, endeavours, can all be fruitless. So I don't think your examples work. Language just lets us extent metaphors almost without limit.